# How to get last nth bars in a chart ? or how to get total number of bars in a chart?

Tags: pine-script

I know how to get reference of the first three bars in a chart:

```
firstBar = bar_index == 0
secondBar = bar_index == 1
thirdBar = bar_index == 2
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the last three bars in a chart.

I guess having the total number of bars would help, but I cannot get that either... For example:

```
totalNumOfBars = ??????? // cannot get that variable

lastBar = bar_index == totalNumOfBars
previousBar = bar_index == totalNumOfBars - 1
antePreviousBar = bar_index == totalNumOfBars - 2
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I tried so far:

```
// for the 1mn timeframe

var TotalNumOfBars = 0

if time == timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), hour(timenow), minute(timenow), 0)
    TotalNumOfBars := bar_index
```

but when I try to reuse this variable, it does not seem to work as expected, for example:

```
plot( bar_index == TotalNumOfBars-2 ? 1 : 0 )
```

never plots "1" in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

`bar_index` is a series and you can access previous value using the history referencing operator

```
totalNumOfBars = bar_index
previousBar = bar_index[1]
antePreviousBar = bar_index[2]
```

[image]

```
//@version=4
study("Number of Bars on the chart", overlay = false)
plot(bar_index)
```

Comment: `bar_index` starts at the first candle, so it is not the total number of bars, rather it is the bar number at the current index. For example, if I have a chart with 3000 bars, `bar_index` will not return 3000, rather it will return 0 for the leftmost bar, 1 for the second bar etc... I need the opposite: I need a way to determine how many total bars the chart has before starting any further indicator calculation. So I would need something that actually returns 3000 whatever the current index is.

Comment: You can't access future bar information (ex: bar_index value of the most recent bar) without feeding the script with all that bars. At every moment of time the script sees only bars to the left and executed bar-by-bar. If you want to get the number of bars on the chart the script should run across all of them first and then you can do calculations backwards, otherwise it would be a delorean pine machine )).

Comment: Added the screenshot as an example.

Comment: Ahaha I love de Delorean comparison. Yes this is what I was thinking too. But all in all, this was my approach to another problem. Maybe I don't need to get the total number of bars for what I need?? My goal is to be able to GET the index number of any bars behind the last bar. I know how to get the close of last bar using `close[1]`, but this is not I am looking for: i need a way to get the exact index number of last bar. Had I had the total number of bars it would be easy, but if I can't get that info, maybe there is another way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in variables `timenow` and `time` to calculate distance from last bar and current bar and in this way estimate total bar count. But this calculation will be inaccurate because of holidays and so on.

Look at [this script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/xNpezfMi-Start-the-Script-on-Last-Nth-Bar-Experimental/) as an example.